# Undefined offset in own helper codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, helper

I want to concatenate characters "/\b" in front of array value $stopwords, and concatenate characters "\b/i" in the back.

**My helper**

```
function addRegex_SW($arrayIn = array()){
    $arrayOut = array();
    $count = count($arrayIn);   
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
       $char1 = "/\b"; 
       $char2 = "\b/i";
       $arrayOut[$i] = $char1.$arrayIn[$i].$char2;
       //echo $arrayOut[$i];
    }
return $arrayOut;
}
```

**My view**

```
$stopwords_Regex = addRegex_SW($stopwords);
```

Then when I run the code

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 317
Filename: helpers/addRegex_helper.php
Line Number: 11
```

Which line is

```
$arrayOut[$i] = $char1.$arrayIn[$i].$char2;
```

I'm sure I had google it, but I dont still get it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for`-loop is *off-by-one*

Change:  `for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)`

To:  `for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)`

Comment: oh 
I forgot array index must be started from 0, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use for, use foreach instead:

```
function addRegex_SW($arrayIn = array()) {
    $arrayOut = array();
    foreach ($arrayIn as $value) {
        $arrayOut[] = '/\b' . $value . '\b/i';
    }
    return $arrayOut;
}
```